# Why do I need a viewport meta tag? I'm using CSS media queries

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm pretty new to creating websites from scratch but I was doing quite some research on meta tags recently, but I'm still left confused. Why do I need a meta viewport tag when I'm already doing CSS media queries?

Comment: There's plenty of information about this on the web, [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) and [here](https://paulund.co.uk/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag). If you don't set a viewport meta tag then a mobile device will display the whole page creating an effect that you've zoomed way out. Thus requiring users to do a lot of pinch zooms and swiping to view text and other content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a few browsers might have bugs which could be fixed with a met viewport. Sometimes when you set sizes in pixels their sizes change according to the screen density and the viewport helps remove that difference. Hope this helped.